# how much connections should I set for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How much connections should I set for PostgreSQL(version 13.x)? by CPU core? the memory size? what value should I choose? how to estimate the value of connection for PostgreSQL? should I estimate like this?

```
(single_thread_memory） = thread_stack（256KB） + binlog_cache_size（32KB） + join_buffer_size（256KB） + sort_buffer_size（256KB） + read_buffer_size（128KB） + read_rnd_buffer_size（256KB）= 1MB
```

Comment: Why would you use a MySQL specific formula for setting things in PostgreSQL?

Comment: what should I do with PostgreSQL connection number estimate. @jjanes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no single formula to definitely determine what a `max_connections` setting should be.  Many factors should probably be considered.

For example:

- How many cores can be allocated to your database server?
- How many connections will be persistent v. transient?  How many of the persistent connections will generally sit idle or idle in transaction (the latter generally less desirable)?
- What is the maximum number of concurrent connections that should be serviced (e.g., for incidental, accidental, and/or intentional denial-of-service prevention)?
- What proportion of your queries are expected to be core-bound v. I/O-bound?
- What other services, if any will your database server be performing and, are those services more core-bound and/or I/O bound?
- Can additional servers with synchronized/replicated data be implemented to handle short- and/or long-term demands (as opposed to increasing `max_connections`?
- If you can perform load testing, such as with `pgbench` and/or with application-specific testing, what queries, concurrencies, etc. revealed core limits, I/O limits, networking limits, etc.!?
- How do you want your environment to fail when overloaded (e.g., is it better to accept as many connections as possible, if they can't all be reasonably serviced, or, is it better to ensure that all successful connections be serviced at the expense of rejecting others)?

Alternatives to `max_connections` that might be of interest:

- Use of `superuser_reserved_connections` for critical/high-priority connection availability.
- Use of extensions (e.g., user-contributed modules like `connection_limits`) that allow per-database, per-user, and per-IP connection limits.
- Use of standalone and/or communal procedural (e.g., PL/pgSQL) wrappers to effectively implement "application"-layer quotas for users, IPs, queries, etc..

Regarding the other aspect(s) of your question, the same type of analysis applies; e.g., how much `work_mem` should be allocated based on the queries being performed.  Consider reading through [PostgreSQL: Server Administration: Server Configuration: Resource Consumption](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html).  Nearly all these settings are worth contemplating when tuning a PostgreSQL server (as are those throughout [PostgreSQL: Server Administration: Server Configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config.html).